# "Extra" parentheses in tensor product

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors

I'm calculating in a context where it's valuable to me to keep "column vectors" in the appropriate format for display. I.e., I would like it if I could figure out how to do something like

```
a = {{1},{0}};
TensorProduct[a,a]
Out: {{1}, {0}, {0}, {0}}
```

As is, what I obtain is `{{{{1}, {0}}}, {{{0}, {0}}}}` . Is there a nice way to get Mathematica to output an honest-to-goodness column vector that will be presented as such by `MatrixForm` as the result of tensoring two column vectors together? Or am I stuck with clumsily excising the extra braces semi-manually?

Answer (score 4):

```
KroneckerProduct[a, a]
```

> {{1}, {0}, {0}, {0}}